# How to maintain facebook session inside android app for making wall post later using me/feed edge?

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

My android app asks for facebook login initially and then user can use the app and add some note for any of his/her taggable_friend. As soon as a user adds a note with his taggable_friend, I want to create a post on that user's wall and tag his/her friends inside that post using me/feed edge but till that time I am not able to retain the facebook session and it is requiring facebook login again to get session.

**Is there any way through which we can retain facebook session after login and create wall post by using me/feed edge later using facebook Android SDK?**

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue like you. Please check if after login you "closeAndClearTokenInformation", because if you do, that means you need to create a new session. If you didn't close it, then it should work (for me it's working), but when a user logs out, you must closeAndClear.. otherwise, it's an exception.